# Add External C Library in a Visual C++ Application - "Error LNK2028" & "Error LNK2019"

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, linker

I am working on a C++ Windows Form Application in Visual Studio 2019.

I want to use some functions of the external library EDFlib. EDFlib is a programming library for C/C++ which consists of only two files (.c and .h).

Here, a simple code that writes data in an EDF file when I click on a button:

```
#include "edflib.h"

// [...]

    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
    {
        double buf[200];
        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
            buf[i] = i;

        int hdl;
        hdl = edfopen_file_writeonly("test.edf", EDFLIB_FILETYPE_EDFPLUS, 1);
        
        // [...]

        edfwrite_physical_samples(hdl, buf);
        edfclose_file(hdl);
    }

// [...]
```

I have the 2 following errors:

```
Erreur  LNK2028 jeton non résolu (0A000038) "extern "C" int __cdecl edfopen_file_writeonly(char const *,int,int)" (?edfopen_file_writeonly@@$$J0YAHPBDHH@Z) référencé dans la fonction "private: void __clrcall TestEDF::MyForm::button1_Click(class System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)" (?button1_Click@MyForm@TestEDF@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)
&
Erreur  LNK2019 symbole externe non résolu "extern "C" int __cdecl edfopen_file_writeonly(char const *,int,int)" (?edfopen_file_writeonly@@$$J0YAHPBDHH@Z) référencé dans la fonction "private: void __clrcall TestEDF::MyForm::button1_Click(class System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)" (?button1_Click@MyForm@TestEDF@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)
```

I tried to read documentation about these errors.
But I am not an C/C++ expert. I don't know what to do. I need some help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing the errors state that you have unresolved symbols,
it means that you are calling functions that you have a declaration for (from the #include "edflib.h") that the linker tries to find during the build process but have no definition.
it seems like you just included the header of the library, but you need to also link with it.
I don't know what IDE you use but you should look up how to link libraries to your projects in C++.
there is a lot of information about creating and linking libraries online that should help you solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You Should Give Extern "C" Method and Add the Library into It, Check

https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp

You Cannot Externally Add C Libraries in C++